# How to activate shape key by proximity of another object?

Tags: shape-keys

Like when you can use dynamic paint to apply displacement on certain parts of mesh and animate it like a brush stroke. My question is, whether you can activate a shape key the same way.

Comment: Since a shape key is driven by only one value, I don't think it is possible to only affect parts of a mesh to take the form of one shape key over another one in the rest of the mesh

Comment: @Gorgious relative shape keys come with a vertex group to weight influence. You can paint the shape key in, by weight-painting into the  vertex group. But I can't for the life of me get DP weights or Weight Proximity Modifier weights to act as that painting. Something to do with order of evaluation? Or maybe I'm missing something. Workflow painful.

Comment: @RobinBetts Well, as they say the best way to get any information on internet is to propose a wrong answer. I tested it too and couldn't get it to work. It should be straightforward though. Maybe a bug ? Maybe you are right and shape keys arre evaluated before modifiers ? Makes sense, but then it really limits the use of the "vertex group" field in the shape keys

Comment: One of my (very few) Blender bugbears. I think XSI / Houdini etc. have this better. Weights at the bottom of everything, so selection by weight for proportional. editing, for precise control, and things like a weighted, pivoted LocRotScale 'Simple Transform' modifier.. which could replace quite a few of the other modifiers, keeping  the interface minimal and powerful.

Comment: You can do it simply with sorcar addon https://youtu.be/PH6lorjaY3Y just set sorcar to realtime and use a custom object node it will do the job

Comment: @Gorgious If you don't want to do it with answer/addon below, is also possible with vg-limited surface deform of a shapekeyed duplicate-- use proximity to fill the vg used to limit the SD.  See https://blenderartists.org/t/morph-by-proximity/1277617 for more details.